# Preventing race condition during multithreading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, race-condition

I am calling a large method via multiple threads and it has been quite difficult to prevent deadlock and race conditions using synclock around global field incrementing.  The method calls other methods, and I am wondering if the threads would race in those other methods that are chained as well(?).

My thoughts are that if I instead instantiate a class, start the thread in the constructor, and then instantiate as objects and their methods all method calls in the first method, race conditions should be avoided.

An instantiated class owns its methods as well, so I believe methods and sub methods in an instantiated class should never race between each other.  I therefore believe I could instantiate the class numerous times instead of even using threads -- and let GC catch up (may be inefficient?).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work better instead of SyncLock:

```
        Interlocked.Increment(myGlobalVariable)
```

Edit: I don't believe your theories about putting the methods in classes will help to prevent a data race. It should not matter where the methods are defined, if they attempt to modify the same data from different threads without an effective synchronization technique (e.g, a mutex), then a data race is a definite possibility.

Comment: One other question, what is the best practice technique if you open e.g. 1000 threads and they all run the same method (subroutine), and you need to increment global counters and update global arrays within this method?  Even if you can get the global elements out of the method, how are most sending the array vector updates back to something global from each thread?

Comment: I think 1000 threads on my PC would be a really bad idea, if it's even possible. How many physical and logical processors does the computer have where you plan to run this program?

Comment: I decided to keep things under control using a ThreadPool.  Also, using Synclock Me ... End Synclock works out to be almost a problem-free approach.